# global name maxLengthPOI not defined in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I have trouble understanding this strange behavior of Global variable in Python

I would like to explain the code is brief:
Here I have a function populate_sheet, that compares the same column in two different dataframes and returns another dataframe having uncommon records.

Next, If the columnName is u'Lead-Programme of interest'. I want to the processing of the column as per the function modifyPoI_0, that returns the first element of the tuple.

Here is where the problem is, I have defined a variable maxLengthPOI, and made it global, so that it contains the maximum length of the tuple in the column u'Lead-Programme of interest'

Running this code gives ERROR: global name maxlengthPOI not defined

```
def populate_sheet(df, input, output, sheet_name, sheet, columnName, sheetInputIndex, sheetOutputIndex ):

    differentPosition = pd.notnull(output[columnName]) & (input[columnName] != output[columnName])  

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [sheet[sheetInputIndex], sheet[sheetOutputIndex]] )
    df[sheet[sheetInputIndex]] = pd.Series(input.loc[differentPosition, columnName])    
    df[sheet[sheetOutputIndex]] = pd.Series(output.loc[differentPosition, columnName])   

    if columnName == u'Lead-Programme of interest':
    #Identify the max length of the tuple : maxLengthPOI 
    #THROWS ERROR: Global name maxLengthPOI is not defined.
        maxLengthPOI = 1  
        def modifyPoI_0(value):
            global maxLengthPOI
            if type(value) == tuple:
                if maxLengthPOI < len(value):
                    maxLengthPOI = len(value)
                return value[0]
            else:
                return value

        df[sheet[sheetOutputIndex]] = df[sheet[sheetOutputIndex]].apply(modifyPoI_0)  

    output.loc[differentPosition, columnName] = [ '=' + sheet_name + '!' + xl_rowcol_to_cell(i+1,sheetOutputIndex ) 
                                           for i in range(sum(differentPosition))]

    return df
```

But when I run a simple script

```
ser = pd.Series([(1, 2), (3, 4, 5, 6), 1, 2])
maxLengthPOI = 1      
def modifyPoI_0(value):
    global maxLengthPOI
        #basically in LeadPoI if its a tuple then return the 
    if type(value) == tuple:
        if maxLengthPOI < len(value):
            maxLengthPOI = len(value)
            return value[0]
        else:
            return value
ser.apply(modifyPoI_0)
```

correctly gives output

```
0          (1, 2)
1    (3, 4, 5, 6)
2            None
3            None
and maxLengthPOI = 4
```

How come we have this strange behaviour, where in the first case it throws an error and in the second case the same exact code works correctly as expected

Comment: Well you don't define `maxLengthPOI` before your first function...

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it doesnt change anything. it still gives the same error

Comment: you still declare it inside the function `populate_sheet`... A global cannot be created in a function.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
#THROWS ERROR: Global name maxLengthPOI is not defined.
        def modifyPoI_0(value):
            global maxLengthPOI
```

`maxLengthPOI` does not exists.

As you see in the first code you posted, `maxLengthPOI` is not `global` at the OUTER `def`. So when you call `modifyPoI_0` it does not exists, as it cant get out of `populate_sheet`. Make it `global` there as well, and it wont be a problem.

The `global` stuff can be considered as: If you DON'T define `global` and you change a variable inside a function, the value will NOT change globally, it will ONLY change inside the function.

Consider this:

```
x = 2
print(x)
def func():
    x = 4
    print(x)
func()
print(x)

print('----')

x = 2
print(x)
def func2():
    global x
    x = 4
    print(x)
func2()
print(x)
```

This prints:

```
2
4
2
# See? x haven't changed, even i called a function which changes its value (It actually changed inside the function as you can see, but not globally)
----
2
4
4
# Now x changed, because i made the variable global, so it 'got out' of the function after its change
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the purpose of global keyword. In fact, my question is how come the same code but used in 2 different cases produces different behaviour. ( an error in the first case and the correct behaviour as expected of global variable in the second case) . If you see my post you could see in the second case the maxLengthPOI was indeed 4, which is what I expected of global varibale.

Comment: As you see in the first case, `maxLengthPOI` is not global at the OUTER def. So when you call `modifyPoI_0` it does not exists, as it cant get out of `populate_sheet`. Make it global there as well, and it wont be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def populate_sheet(df, input, output, sheet_name, sheet, columnName, 
    maxLengthPOI = 1  # defined in populate_sheet() so local to populate_sheet(), not global!
    def modifyPoI_0(value):
        global maxLengthPOI # not defined (as a global)
```

Define `maxLengthPOI` outside of any function to use it as a global variable. Or best: avoid globals when you can and use extra args instead (possible most of the time).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my whole flow is quite complex. I have one main function and the function populate_sheet is reached after passing through 3 modules and several functions(5 to be precise).
So I tried defining maxLengthPOI = 1 in the first main and then importing this module inside the populate_sheet module. But it still gives the same error